# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file' using segmentation_models

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to use segmentation models but I can't fix this error. I've searched for this particular
one but couldn't find an answer. I'm using pycharm and this error is linked to this specific line of code
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'

```
model1 = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, weights=None,
                 encoder_weights='imagenet',
                 classes=num_classes,
                 activation='softmax',
                 decoder_block_type = 'upsampling')
```

which is also the 83rd. I searched in the documentation and apparently the versions of tensorflow keras etc satisfy the requirements.I really don't know what to do given the fact that I really tried to install and uninstall everything in many combinations in order to get this piece of code to work.Thank you all for your help and time! Below there's the complete error, hoping it might help you!

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\main.py", line 83, in <module>
        model1 = sm.Unet('resnet34', weights=None,
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\segmentation_models\__init__.py", line 34, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\segmentation_models\models\unet.py", line 221, in Unet
        backbone = Backbones.get_backbone(
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\segmentation_models\backbones\backbones_factory.py", line 103, in get_backbone
        model = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\classification_models\models_factory.py", line 78, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **new_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\classification_models\models\resnet.py", line 314, in ResNet34
        return ResNet(
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\classification_models\models\resnet.py", line 280, in ResNet
        load_model_weights(model, model_params.model_name,
      File "C:\Users\Giulia\PycharmProjects\multiclass_new\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\classification_models\weights.py", line 25, in load_model_weights
        weights_path = keras_utils.get_file(
    AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file'
```

Comment: In Colab, I got the same error, and tried to solve it by looking at the issues in github, but it didnot work for me. Then moved to the kaggle, and problem solved by adding `%env SM_FRAMEWORK=tf.keras` before the import

Answer (score 23):

You can try:

```
import segmentation_models as sm

sm.set_framework('tf.keras')

sm.framework()
```

Worked for me on google colab!

Comment: This worked on tf 2.7 as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on Linux and this didn't didn't solve it. :(

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, try importing the module EfficientNetB0 directly, as the code below:

```py
import efficientnet.tfkeras as efn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but with vgg u-net model , This worked for me

```
!apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

!pip install opencv-python

!pip install git+https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras

from keras_segmentation.models.unet import vgg_unet
```

or check here how it's implemented
https://gitee.com/sanyanjie/image-segmentation-keras

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Colab, I recommend running:

```
import os
import time
os.environ['SM_FRAMEWORK'] = 'tf.keras'
time.sleep(3)
import semantic_model as sm
```

or:

```
os.environ['SM_FRAMEWORK'] # and import statements on seperate cells
```

it may be there is someprocess with setting of environ variable and working i dont know how it works but it works

Answer (score -1):

The other answer provided here didn't work for me. Instead, upgrading keras did the trick for me via:

```
pip install --upgrade keras
```